# Highcharts time X axis

Tags: highcharts, time-series, axis

I would like to ask if somebody knows how to set X axis in Highcharts to time. My aplication is taking data from database and the frequency of the samples is 250ms. I want the X axis not to show counted values but something like time. I render 2500 values at once so that means 10 secs. The best would be to have on X axis and a mark there every 0.5 sec that means every 125 samples a mark. Like (0 samples = 0 sec);(125 samples = 0,5 sec);(500 samples = 1 sec);(725 samples = 1.5 sec)

Thank you for your opinions.....

```
                                chart () {
                                    var options = {
                                        chart: { 
                                            renderTo: 'services',
                                            type: 'line', 
                                            animation: 'false'
                                        },

                                      plotOptions: {
                                            series: {
                                                animation: {
                                                    duration: 10000
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },

                                        series: [{marker: {
                                                    enabled: false
                                                }}]
                                      };
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? Do you just need to have the X-Axis "ticks" to be drawn at an interval of "0.5" and have them have a label with the suffix of "sec" or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/) might help

Comment: I need to mark every 125 samples by half a secod......now it is marking every 500 rendered samples chart by defalult. So the sequence on X axis is doing mark after 500 samples rendered. We can say it marks every 500 sample. So it is like 0.......500......1000......1500.....2000......2500. I need to have it after every 125 and it should be marked by 0.5 sec. Every 125 sample is 0.5 second.

Comment: And on the top of that it should represent the timeflow of the chart like something that shows how long the chart is running. Now the timeflow goes again from zero each time I render chart with fresh samples. @apokryfos

Comment: Have you looked at the demos ( http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ ) and the API documentation ( http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis ) ? Unless you have more specific issues, that should be all you need to answer your question.

Comment: Yes I did  but i did not find the solution....the tickInterval should be 250 type is linear......but instead of displayed 250 I need to have 0.5, instead of 500 i need to have 1 and so on.....everything there is just datetime based, but that is not right for me I am rendering chart in cycle so after first 2500 samples rendered the whole chart is rendered again. X axis should be independent and continue in counting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a custom label formatter. For example...

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return (baseTime + (this.value / 500)) + " sec";
        }
    }
},
```

where baseTime is the time of the first data point.

Documentation for custom label formatter can be found at...

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: YES! it shows the time on X axis the only one problem there is that after rendering new bunch of data the time goes again from zero....

Comment: @FilipMartiak Then change `baseTime` value when you are rendering new bunch of data.